# Find previous occurrence of an element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following html:

```
<h4>Testing</h4>
<h3>Test</h3>
<h3>Test2</h3>
<h4>Testing2</h4>
```

If I have the element `<h3>Test2</h3>` referenced in a variable, how can I find `<h4>Testing</h4>`? The one **before** the referenced element, not after.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`.previous_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
element.previous_sibling
```

Or, [`.find_previous_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling) to explicitly find the first preceding `h4` tag:

```
element.find_previous_sibling('h4')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <h4>Testing</h4>
... <h3>Test</h3>
... <h3>Test2</h3>
... <h4>Testing2</h4>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> element = soup.find('h3', text='Test')
>>> element.find_previous_sibling('h4')
<h4>Testing</h4>
```