# How to get count of tag with a specific class before a certain element using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to count all the `<a>` tags containing the class name `md-headline` and that are located before the link containing the title "Dupont Lewis".

To define the position of the link ("Dupont Lewis") within the page, I am using the following code:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sortlist.fr/pub'
response= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())

soup.a = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "md-headline"})
search = soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
if search:
    position = find_all_previous('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
    print(position.count)
else:
    print('None')
```

But I keep on getting 0 for some reason.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find previous occurrence of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681602/find-previous-occurrence-of-an-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find all previous elements

```
link = soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
previous_md_headlines = link.find_all_previous("a", {"class": "md-headline"})
```

### Find all next elements

```python
link = soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
next_md_headlines = link.find_all_next("a", {"class": "md-headline"})
```

### Original question: Why do I keep getting 0 links with class `md-headline` prior to the link with title "Dupont Lewis"?

On the web page "https://www.sortlist.fr/pub", the first anchor element with class `md-headline` also happens to be the same anchor element with the title "Dupont Lewis", which is why the previous element count will always be zero (unless the web page changes).

### Complete Example

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sortlist.fr/pub'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

link = soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
print(f"link: {link}")
previous_md_headlines = link.find_all_previous("a", {"class": "md-headline"})
next_md_headlines = link.find_all_next("a", {"class": "md-headline"})

print(f"\n\nFound {len(previous_md_headlines)} previous md-headlines.")
print("Previous md-headline links:\n")
print(*previous_md_headlines, sep="\n\n")

print(f"Found {len(next_md_headlines)} next md-headlines.")
print("Next md-headline links:\n")
print(*next_md_headlines, sep="\n\n")
```

#### Output

```
link: <a class="s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate" ng-click='setExpertiseAndLocation({"expertise":{"id":84,"name":"Publicité","title":"Agences de Publicité","slug":"pub","imageUrl":"/images/expertises/84.jpg"}})' sl-link="xx-L2FnZW5jeS9kdXBvbnQtbGV3aXM=" target="_blank" title="Dupont Lewis">Dupont Lewis</a>


Found 0 previous md-headlines.
Previous md-headline links:

Found 49 next md-headlines.
Next md-headline links:

<a class="s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate" ng-click='setExpertiseAndLocation({"expertise":{"id":84,"name":"Publicité","title":"Agences de Publicité","slug":"pub","imageUrl":"/images/expertises/84.jpg"}})' sl-link="xx-L2FnZW5jeS9jb25jZXB0b3J5LTVmMjliMzFhLWExY2YtNDRlYS1iYzA4LWJiMzg2MTkyMmM1OQ==" target="_blank" title="The Collective Story">The Collective Story</a>

<a class="s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate" ng-click='setExpertiseAndLocation({"expertise":{"id":84,"name":"Publicité","title":"Agences de Publicité","slug":"pub","imageUrl":"/images/expertises/84.jpg"}})' sl-link="xx-L2FnZW5jeS90aGUtY3Jldw==" target="_blank" title="The Crew Communication">The Crew Communication</a>

<a class="s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate" ng-click='setExpertiseAndLocation({"expertise":{"id":84,"name":"Publicité","title":"Agences de Publicité","slug":"pub","imageUrl":"/images/expertises/84.jpg"}})' sl-link="xx-L2FnZW5jeS9ub3ZlbWJyZQ==" target="_blank" title="Novembre - Creative Business Partner">Novembre - Creative Business Partner</a>
...
```

Comment: Ah great, it's working fine now! thank you so much Christopher!

Comment: And how can I anticipate if the link is paginated please? i am stuck on that front!

Comment: @yassineattigui Have a look at this article: [Web Scraping a Site with Pagination using BeautifulSoup](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/webscraping-a-site-with-pagination-using-beautifulsoup-fa0a09804445) If that does not provide what you need, consider asking a separate question on Stack Overflow.